# SQL : select other columns with nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have no data in the database for the current week as its not ended. Data is entered on Monday the following week. Hence the query is showing no results. The query is created using a join.

```
select 
    sm.sugar_mill_name, mbz.mill, fhi.hczname as zone, sd.name as station, 
    round(nvl(wd.dvalue, 0), 1) as Station_Reading
from 
    mill_by_zone mbz
join 
    sugar_mills sm on sm.sugar_mill_name = mbz.mill
join 
    fca_hcz_info fhi on fhi.hcz = mbz.zone
join 
    zone_by_station zbs on zbs.zone = fhi.hcz
join 
    station_details sd on sd.station_num = zbs.station
join 
    weekly_data wd on wd.station_num = sd.station_num and wd.station_num = zbs.station
where 
    wd.record_year = 2019 
    and wd.record_week = 19 
    and wd.dcode = 1
```

How do I display constant data i.e. `sm.sugar_mill_name, mbz.mill, fhi.hczname as zone, sd.name as station`

`round(nvl(wd.dvalue,0),1)` as Station_Reading is currently blank as no data has been inputed yet.

[image: Results]

Comment: you could use union and show the constant value for those column

Comment: Try to do LEFT JOIN against `weekly_data`, that should give you a result from the other tables even when `weekly_data` is empty (if I understood the question correctly)

Comment: I have used the left outer join and left join however still no constant data

Comment: Maybe you should add some sample data then to help clarify your question. Just as a test, what happens if you remove `round(nvl(wd.dvalue, 0), 1)` from the select and the join against `weekly_data` alltogether? Will that give you the correct "constant" data?

Comment: wd.station_num is blank hence the join with station_details and zone_by_station is joining on nothing. I assume that's why there is no data. How do I select the remainder fields though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `LEFT JOIN`s to bring in the weekly data.  When doing this, you also need to move the filtering conditions on the column to the `ON` clause:

```
select sm.sugar_mill_name, mbz.mill, fhi.hczname as zone, sd.name as station, 
    round(coalesce(wd.dvalue, 0), 1) as Station_Reading
from sugar_mills sm join
     mill_by_zone mbz
     on sm.sugar_mill_name = mbz.mill join
     fca_hcz_info fhi
     on fhi.hcz = mbz.zone join 
     zone_by_station zbs
     on zbs.zone = fhi.hcz join 
     station_details sd
     on sd.station_num = zbs.station left join 
     weekly_data wd
     on wd.station_num = sd.station_num and
        wd.station_num = zbs.station and 
        wd.record_year = 2019 and
        wd.record_week = 19 and
        wd.dcode = 1;
```

Comment: please note the current query does work however. It shows 0 values also. Please see image I added. How would I also hide the 0 fields

Comment: @ZainNabi . . . I'm confused.  I thought you specifically want to show the `0` values.

Comment: in the event when there is data there are other stations which are  0s

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of joins in SQL Server:

- INNER
- LEFT
- RIGHT
- FULL OUTER

Have a look at [here](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg) what each of these joins means, how it works and learn when to use certain type of join. In your specific case, I think you need to use **LEFT JOIN** on **weekly_data**.

P.S. As a best practice, instead of just writing the term JOIN, use full join name (INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, etc.)